# ClientToken getting UNDEFINED?

Tags: node.js, braintree

I want to generate `clientToken` by braintree but I'm getting UNDEFINED.....

```
var braintree = require("braintree");

// generate client token code

export const braintreeToken = (req, res) => {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(501).send(err);

      console.log("hello");
    } else {
      res.send(response.clinetToken);
    }
  });
};
```

Braintree API KEY

```
var gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "64kmt6hch5g32nrj",
  publicKey: "48k2jnnsbfkjw37g",
  privateKey: "5556a7a162f3046de1166054acd3a562",
});
```

Comment: There is a typo. It should be `response.clientToken`, but you wrote `response.clinetToken`.

Comment: yes but I have changed the type mistake ....I am not getting response....and thus not clientToken